# How to extend parent data object to child object in php7 to access parent data Symfony 5

Tags: symfony, inheritance, dependency-injection, php-7

I have searched for many hours and spent many hours trying to debug my code, I am rewriting this question as I believed it caused confusion hence why it hasn't been answered yet. I hope my clarification makes it clear.

Previously I was dependency injecting the BaseHelper class but this was causing readability issues as the files get larger and requires more services.

```
namespace App\Helpers\Users\Profiles;

use App\Core\BaseHelper;

class ProfileHelper
{
    public function __construct(BaseHelper $helper)
    {
        $this->base = $helper;
        $this->data = $this->base->data;
    }

    public function getPageData()
    {
        return $this->data;
    }
}
```

BaseHelper file used to call user functions which are specific to the basehelper and not called from any other file:

```
namespace App\Core;

use App\Services\security\SecurityService;
use App\Services\users\UserService;

class BaseHelper
{
    private $security;
    private $user;

    public function __construct(SecurityService $security, UserService $user)
    {
        $this->sec = $security;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->data = $this->checkUserExists();
    }

    private function checkUserExists()
    {
        if ($this->sec->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->identity = $this->sec->data();
            return $data = $this->user->parseUser($this->identity->getUserCode());
        } else {
            return $data = (object) [];
        }
    }
}
```

ProfileHelper then retrieves the data object and appends page specific data, this is where the error appears as it says that the $data object is undefined:

```
namespace App\Helpers\Users\Profiles;

use App\Core\BaseHelper;

class ProfileHelper extends BaseHelper
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = $this->data;
    }


    public function getPageData()
    {
        return $this->data;
    }
}
```

I have extrapolated the relevant code to show the example of the error, the main files have a lot more services injected in, hence why I am trying to extend the basehelper to access the data property. The project is built using symfony 5

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? The given properties are not defined anywhere in your classes, so you could start by doing this

Comment: I spent many hours trying to debug this error, I also looked at the definitions for inheritance in php, the errors which return are either undefined property or parent construct requires to variables to be called.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot construct a child class without also constructing the parent class. In your child, call `parent::_construct()` and input the required arguments. Then `$data`, `$user` and `$sec` will be defined.

```php
class ProfileHelper extends BaseHelper
{
    protected $data;

    public function __construct(SecurityService $security, UserService $user , AssetService $assets, SocialService $social)
    {
        parent::_construct($security, $user);
        $this->assets = $assets;
        $this->social = $social;
        $this->data = $this->data;
    }
...
```

See [PHP's Constructors and Destructors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) for more information.

Comment: I understand your premise, however what confuses me though is: what is the point of extending the parent class if I have to redefine the service files that are specific to that class. Surely I should be able to extrapolate the data from the parent class without redefining the services, but my other issue is how does this help simplify the file if I am having to still DI the same services as the parent class, as I show in my first coding block the helper file is getting very hard to read

Comment: I've added a a link to the php site for more information. I don't know how to answer your additional questions. I think this answers your initial question.